# I don't know why this query means this sentence

Tags: sql

```
select distinct S.ID, S.name
from student as S
where not exists (
    (select course_id from course where dept_name = ’Biology’)
    except
    (select T.course_id from takes as T where S.ID = T.ID)
);
```

This query says in my book that it means

> "Find all students who have taken all courses offered in the Biology
>   department"

The table is as follows: 
student(ID, name, dept_name,tot_cred) 
takes(ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year, grade) 
course(course_id, title, dept_name, credits)

I thought the query didn't work because student table didn't have a courseID.

Why is the execution of this query the same as described above?

Comment: The sub query gets all biology classes minus the ones taken by a student. Left are the biology classes that the student has not taken. The main query says hence: give me all students that don't have any untaken biology classes. The `DISTINCT` is superfluous, as there must be no duplicate students in a student table of course. I must say that this makes me put your book into question. Paving each and every query with unnecessary `DISTINCT` is a typical beginners' issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought the query didn't work because student table didn't have a courseID.

Note that `course_id` is never referred to except from the table `course` (`select course_id from course`) or the table `takes` (`select T.course_id from takes as T`).  The query doesn't ever refer to `student.course_id` so your question belies your misunderstanding of what the query is doing.

The query is a bit confusing because it effectively employs a double negative.  The `where not exists` clause more or less says "find all students where, if we take the set of biology courses offered and remove all of the courses the student has taken, the result is the empty set."

```
-- Where the following set is empty...
where not exists (
    -- All of the biology courses offered...
    (select course_id from course where dept_name = ’Biology’)

    -- EXCEPT those that the student has taken.
    except
    (select T.course_id from takes as T where S.ID = T.ID)
)
```

If we take all offered biology courses and remove the courses that the student has taken, and the result is an empty set, the only possible explanation is that the student has taken all of the biology courses offered. (Aside: It's also possible that there are no biology courses offered, in which case the student still has taken all of the biology courses offered -- this is called [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).)

Comment: not exists is considered to return true values when the set is empty after the sentence. But I still don't know why the results print out students who have taken all the classes in biology.

Comment: @Kim Read the answer carefully, and desk-check what the query does. If the course IDs for all of the biology classes are 1, 2, and 3, and the student has taken courses 1, 2, 3, and 4, what happens when you take the first set and remove from it all elements that are also in the second set?

Comment: @cdhowie I know it's an empty set, but I don't know how "not exists" works and why the results print out all the courses in biology.

Comment: @Kim `NOT EXISTS` simply asserts that the following set/subquery is empty. Therefore, if the student has taken all of the biology classes, the `NOT EXISTS (...)` clause evaluates as true, and the student record being evaluated is included in the result set. The results should not print out all of the biology courses, the results should be all of the students _who have taken **all** of the biology courses._

Comment: @cdhowie What would happen if there were students who did not carry out biology department but took course in other department?

Comment: @Kim Then the subquery after `NOT EXISTS` would not be empty, therefore `NOT EXISTS` would evaluate as false and the student would not be included in the result set. Just as your book says, the query returns only students who have taken every offered Biology course.

Answer (score 1):

The query is saying:  "There does not exist a course in the biology department that the student did not take".

The second subquery (after the `except`) is getting all the courses that the student takes.  These are removed from all courses in the biology department.  So, if a student took all courses in that department, the result would be no rows.  Otherwise, the result are the rows the student did not take.

The `select distinct` is highly misleading.  The student table should not have duplicates.

I prefer using aggregation for these types of queries:

```
select t.student_id
from takes t join
     course c
     on t.course_id = c.course_id 
where c.dept_name = 'Biology'
group by t.student_id
having count(distinct t.course_id) = (select count(*) from course c2 where c2.dept_name = 'Biology');
```

For me (at least), the logic here more clearly matches "students would took all courses in the Biology department".